# Django LiveServerTestCase hangs when I run my tests

Tags: django, django-testing, django-tests

I am trying to set up a LiveServerTestCase with Django 1.10.4. Whenever I run my tests the the browser opens up hangs and can't reach localhost. My frontend is a separate angular/react app. So, I build my static assets using grunt build and then run collectstatic. Below is the code for my tests.

```
from django.test.testcases import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



class ChromeTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(ChromeTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
        cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        cls.wait = WebDriverWait(cls.driver, 10)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
        super(ChromeTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_user_sign_up_from_form(self):
        self.driver.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/'))

        self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="email"]')))
        email_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//input[@id="email"]')
        email_input.send_keys("test@gmail.com")
        password_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//input[@id="password"]')
        password_input.send_keys("secret")

        signup_button = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="signup_button"]')
        signup_button.click()

        url = self.live_server_url + '/home'
        self.assertEquals(self.driver.current_url, url)
```

Does anyone know why my tests can't reach the test server?

Also, The url my test server creates is https.

Comment: Did you debug your js and network? If you comment your teardown the browser remains and you can open devel tools. And for js I found safer phantomjs browser.

Comment: When I check the console I am getting an error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED on localhost:8011/ and in the network tab I am getting a failed to load resource error. Thanks for the phantomjs suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue ended up being related to a middleware that redirects requests to https on production. I got my tests working by removing that middleware.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable `DEBUG` with `LiveServerTestCase`, adding these lines:

```python
from django.test import override_settings

@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
class ChromeTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
```